# How can I sync the html/session used between Django's 'Client' and Selenium's webdriver

Tags: python, django, selenium, lettuce

I'm trying to test that logged in users can log out on my Django site with Lettuce, Selenium and lettuce_webdriver.

In my terrain.py I have:

```
@before.all
def setup_browser():
    profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
    profile.set_preference('network.dns.disableIPv6', True)
    world.browser = webdriver.Firefox(profile)
    world.client = Client(HTTP_USER_AGENT='Mozilla/5.0')
```

And then when I 'login':

```
@step(r'I am logged in as "(\w*)"')
def log_in(step, name):
    world.client.login(username=name, password=name)
```

And I go to my site:

```
And I go to "localhost:8000"
    I find a link called "Logout ?" that goes to "/logout"

@step(r'I find a link called "(.*?)" that goes to "(.*?)"$')
def find_link(step, link_name, link_url):
    print(world.browser.page_source)
    elem = world.browser.find_element_by_xpath(r'//a[@href="%s"]' % link_url)
    eq_(elem.text, link_name)
```

But my page_source shows I am not logged in. This kind of makes sense...in that `client` and `browser` aren't talking to each other. But is this possible, or do I need to login 'manually' by clicking links with selenium etc?

I'd like to do this:

```
 world.browser.page_source = world.client.get(world.browser.current_url).content
```

But page_source can't be changed. Can I feed Selenium from django's client some how?

Edit: Following [Loius'](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27990317/1075247) advice below, my 'I am logged in as ...' step is as below. I added the if/else to just check my suspicions. My client is still setup as above (see `setup_browser` step above)

```
@step(r'I am logged in as "(\w*)"')
def log_in(step, name):
    world.client.login(username=name, password=name)
    if world.client.cookies:
        session_key = world.client.cookies["sessionid"].value
        world.browser.add_cookie({'name':'sessionid', 'value':session_key})
        world.browser.refresh()
    else: 
        raise Exception("No Cookies!")
```

All the advice I've seen is to login first. Without my check, I get this:

```
  Scenario: Logged in users can logout                       # \gantt_charts\features\index.feature:12
    Given I am logged in as "elsepeth"                                # \gantt_charts\features\steps.py:25
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\lettuce\core.py", line 144, in __call__
        ret = self.function(self.step, *args, **kw)
      File "D:\Django_Projects\gAnttlr\gantt_charts\features\steps.py", line 27, in log_in
        session_key = world.client.cookies["sessionid"].value
    KeyError: 'sessionid'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've not tried doing *exactly* what you are trying to do but I've done something similar. What you need to do is set a cookie like this on your Selenium instance after you've logged into your Django site with your `Client` instance:

```
driver.add_cookie({'name': 'sessionid', 'value': session_key})
```

The name should be equal to your `SESSION_COOKIE_NAME` setting on the Django site (`sessionid` is the default). You need to figure out the value of `session_key`.

You can obtain it from a `Client` instance like this:

```
    session_key = client.cookies["sessionid"].value
```

Note that Selenium won't be able to set the cookie *for some browsers* if `SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE` is `True`. You should have this setting be `True` for your production server but if you want your Selenium tests to set your session cookie, then you have to make it `False` for testing.

Once your Selenium instance has the cookie, it will look to Django as if you had logged into it with Selenium. As I said, I do something *similar* in my test suites. (I use something else than `Client` but the principle is the same.)