# Python-Selenium won't wait for my website to refresh?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to test that logged in users can logout.

To tell Selenium I am logged in I [cookie-jack the sessionid](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27990317/1075247), like so:

```
@step(r'I am logged in as "(\w*)"')
def log_in(step, name):
    can_login = world.client.login(username=name, password=name)
    if can_login:
        session_key = world.client.cookies['sessionid'].value
        world.browser.add_cookie({'name':'sessionid', 'value':session_key})
        world.browser.get(world.browser.current_url)
        from time import sleep    #Really should have to do this
        sleep(100)
    else: 
        raise Exception("Could not login with those credentials")
```

I need to refresh for the html to change on 'login', but selenium is taking so long to refresh the page (it's on localhost, which I know can have problems). I do have an implicit wait in my terrain.py:

```
world.browser.implicitly_wait(10)
```

But I don't think it's taking effect. How can I tell selenium to wait for the page to load each time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Implicit wait would not help since it is just telling how long to wait while finding an element.

Instead, you need to [explicitly wait](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/waits.html#explicit-waits) for an element appearing after the page load:

```
world.browser.get(world.browser.current_url)

element = WebDriverWait(world.browser, 50).until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "header"))
)
```

This would tell selenium to wait for at most 50 seconds, checking element existence every 500 milliseconds, think about it as polling.

Comment: Should I still use an implicit wait in my setup or is that redundant? Also can I just use a world.browser.refresh()?

Comment: @Pureferret implicit wait would apply for cases where you don't have an explicit wait - you can leave it if doesn't make it slower and helps. I'm not completely sure what is going on at your end - not enough information to say more..

Comment: Fair enough. I've heard selenium can be slow using localhost, but I've followed all the steps I could see on this and I've not seen any speed up.